# Import PostgreSQL dump on OSX

Tags: sql, database, macos, postgresql, postgres.app

I've only used MySQL before. Postgres is a little different for me. I'm trying to use the Postgres.app for OSX. I have a database dump from our development server, and I want to create the correct user roles and import the database to my local machine so I can do development at home (can't access the database remotely).

I *think* I've created the user. **\du** shows the appropriate user with the CreateDB permission. Then I used **\i ~/dump.sql** which seems to have imported the database. However when I use **\l** to list databases, it doesn't show up. So then I tried logging in with **psql -U *username***, but then it tells me "**FATAL: database *username* does not exist.**" Is that not the right switch for login? It's what the help said.

I'm getting frustrated with something simple so I appreciate any help. With the Postgres.app, how can I create the necessary users with passwords and import the database? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you probably loaded the dump into the database you were connected to. If you didn't specify a database when you started `psql` it'll be the database named after your username. It depends a bit on the options used with `pg_dump` when the dump file was created though.

Try:

```
 psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1

 CREATE DATABASE mynewdb TEMPLATE template0 OWNER whateverowneruser;
 \c mynewdb
 \i /path/to/dump/file.sql
```

Personally, I recommend always using `pg_dump -Fc` to create custom-format dumps instead of SQL dumps. They're a *lot* easier to work with and `pg_restore` is a lot nicer than using `psql` for restoring dumps.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have solved it. I will definitely have to keep in mind the info about `pg_dump`/`pg_restore` usage in the future.

Answer (score 2):

**Mac users: If you are here in 2023 and are on the Mac operating system and you have created a database dump using pg_dump utility**

**A. The dump is taken in SQL format (simple one)**

```
pg_dump -U <USER_NAME> -h <DATABASE_HOST> <DB_NAME> > sample.sql
```

Then in order to restore it use the below command.

First, create the database manually using the command line/terminal

```
psql  -U <USER_NAME>  -h <DATABSE_HOST>
```

Once connected create the database using the command

```
create database test;
\q
```

Now restore the dump using the below command and you are done :)

```
psql  -U <USER_NAME>  -d <DATABSE_NAME> -h <DATABSE_HOST> <  sample.sql
```

For localhost use 127.0.0.1 as the database host.

**(B) Dump is taken in binary format.**

```
pg_dump -U <USER_NAME> -h <DATABASE_HOST> -d <DB_NAME>  -Fc > sample.dump
```

Then in order to restore it use the below command.

First, create the database manually using the command line/terminal

```
psql  -U <USER_NAME>  -h <DATABSE_HOST>
```

Once connected create the database using the command

```
create database test;
\q
```

Now restore the dump using the below command.

```
pg_restore -Fc  -U <USER_NAME>  -d <DATABSE_NAME> -h <DATABSE_HOST>   sample.dump
```

For localhost use 127.0.0.1 as the database host.

Note: Binary backups are a more practical choice for backing up production databases because they provide faster, more reliable, and more consistent backups. However, text backups may still be useful in certain scenarios, such as archiving or manual inspection of the backup file.

Answer (score 0):

`-U <username>` is correct for specifying the username with *psql*, but the last token is the database name here. It's interpreting that you specified no user and the database is **username**. Try adding the database name after, i.e. `psql -U username database`.

See the [psql doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) for more info regarding the myriad switches *psql* supports.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I think my lack of experience with postgres has been a stumbling block for me.